# How to concatenate two exceptions?

Tags: c#, reflection, exception

I have the following piece of code for handling exceptions in my web application:

```
application.Response.Clear();
application.Response.Status = Constants.HttpServerError;
application.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

LogApplicationException(application.Response, exception);
try
{
    WriteViewResponse(exception);
}
// now we're in trouble. lets be as graceful as possible.
catch (Exception exceptionWritingView)
{
    // Exception wrapper = ??
    WriteGracefulResponse(exceptionWritingView);
}
finally
{
    application.Server.ClearError();
}
```

The issue here is that if there's an exception while attempting to render the response as a `ViewResult`, I'm "suppressing" the original exception (in the `View` anyways), and just displaying what caused the error `ViewResult` to throw.

I'd like taking both `exception` and `exceptionWritingView` and make one exception with both, with `exceptionWritingView` at the top.

This would be:

```
exceptionWritingView
    -> inner exceptions of exceptionWritingView
            -> original exception that raised the unhandled exception handler
                       -> its inner exceptions
```

But I can't set the `InnerException` property on my `exception` object. So how could I achieve this?

At "best" I could create a new `Exception` using `new Exception(exceptionWritingView.Message, exception)`, but I'd be losing parts of the `StackTrace` plus I'd be losing any `InnerException`s the `exceptionWritingView` could've had.

Is reflection the only way out here? Would it be that horrible to do it with reflection?

Comment: In Java you call `initCause()` with the old exception (or just pass it to the constructor of the new exception. I'm not sure about C#.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use [**System.AggregateException**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.aspx).

Example:

```cs
WriteGracefulResponse(new AggregateException(new Exception[]
{
    exceptionWritingView,
    originalUnhandledException
}));
```

Comment: definitely the cleanliest option.

Answer (score 0):

You don't set the inner exception through the setter, you set it through the constructor.

```
application.Response.Clear();
application.Response.Status = Constants.HttpServerError;
application.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

LogApplicationException(application.Response, exception);
try
{
    WriteViewResponse(exception);
}
// now we're in trouble. lets be as graceful as possible.
catch (Exception exceptionWritingView)
{
    // Example on how to nest exceptions.
    throw MyException("Error message", exceptionWritingView);
}
finally
{
    application.Server.ClearError();
}
```

Your stack trace will be saved in the inner exception.

Comment: that's not helping me, I need the full `exception` and the full `exceptionWritingView`

Comment: I'm not sure how using inner exceptions isn't helping.  You can reference the original exception by using the InnerException Property.       Try reading this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173163.aspx

Comment: I Get it...In the WriteViewResponse method I'm assuming you have a throw Exception?  That is the point that you would try { [statement] } catch (Exception ex) { throw new Exception("my error message", ex) }

Answer (score 0):

Why to make things complicated? Why not pass `exception` as a parameter into `WriteGracefulResponse` method?

```
...
// now we're in trouble. lets be as graceful as possible. 
catch (Exception exceptionWritingView) 
{ 
   // Exception wrapper = ?? 
   WriteGracefulResponse(exception, exceptionWritingView); 
}
```

You should also rename `exceptionWritingView` to something ending with `exception`, now it confuses readers who think this is a view.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, the biggest problem is that Exceptions provide only getters and this restricts what you are able to do. To solve this, you can inherit from Exception to make its properties settable. In my example class you can initialize FlexibleException which recurrses through a regular exception basically making a copy of it, but a copy that is settable. Then to add a previous exception it can travel down the ladder until it finds the end and tacks on to it, concatenating two exceptions. I've never had to use something like this so this is just something I wrote up and it may have some bugs, but I believe it accomplishes what you are trying to do.

```
application.Response.Clear();
application.Response.Status = Constants.HttpServerError;
application.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

LogApplicationException(application.Response, exception);
try
{
    WriteViewResponse(exception);
}

catch (Exception exceptionWritingView)
{
    FlexibleException lastException = new FlexibleException(exceptionWritingView);
    lastException.AddPreviousException(exception);
    WriteGracefulResponse(lastException);
}
finally
{
    application.Server.ClearError();
}
```

---

```
public class FlexibleException : Exception
{
    public FlexibleException(Exception e)
    {
        this.InnerException = e.InnerException != null ? new FlexibleException(e.InnerException) : null;
        this.StackTrace = e.StackTrace;
    }

    public FlexibleException InnerException { get; set; }

    public string StackTrace { get; set; }

    public void AddPreviousException(Exception e)
    {
            FlexibleException prevException = new FlexibleException(e);
        FlexibleException nextException = this;

        while (true)
        {
            if (nextException.InnerException != null)
            {
               nextException = nextException.InnerException;
               continue;
            }
            else
            {
               nextException = prevException;
               break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: You cannot add a setter to the InnerException or StackTrace through inheritence, but you can add a separate setter property WritableStackTrace and override StackTrace to return it's value (technically making it settable).

Another alternative to writing a derived Exception class would be to write a function which works very similar to AddPreviousException, except that it will drill down into and exception object, then recreate it passing the exception you want to concatenate to its constructor, then work your way up swallowing each exception.

Comment: This is a really convoluted solution, I feel much better off just using `AggregateException` than trying to reinvent the wheel.. thanks for the input though!

Comment: Oh yeah, I agree if you want simplicity and just want to pass multiple exceptions AggregateException is perfect. One advantage this way would have is that you can maintain the chronological order by having your parent/child exceptions properly nested whereas an AggregateExp is a flat list in which it may be hard to tell which exception occurred first.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that one when I implemented `AggregateException`, but as long as I add the exceptions in the order they were thrown, I can present them chronologically.